# what are the best practices do use pubnub with redux-saga?

Tags: redux, pubnub, redux-saga

what are the best practices to use pubnub using generators in redux-saga. To dispatch actions on Connect, on disconnect, on events, to retrieve history messages and so on?

The problem is that PubNub provides a callback API instead of promises, and some functions have more than one callback, like connect, disconnect.

For publish with have this function:

```
pubnub.publish({
      channel,
      message,
      callback: (message) => {
        // dispatch action with new message/event
      },
      error: (err) => {
        // dispatch action of error
      }
    });
```

For subscribe with have this one:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
   channel,
   connect: () => //dispatch action of connect
   callback: (data) => // dispatch action of new data
   error: (err) => // dispatch action of error
}
```

Comment: Pubnub API only provide callbacks not promises, so this make it harder to handle with sagas. How can I integrate with subscribe to dispatch an action inside a saga when a new event/message arrives? How to handle connectivity issues?